# Is my negation of this if statement correct?

Tags: c, if-statement

I am currently working with some legacy code that has this if statement:

```
if(c == 30 || c == 3 || c == 4 || r == 'Y' || t == 'X' ||( s>= 50000 && s <= 50999))
{
  //do nothing
}
else
{
  function1();
}
```

I am trying to eliminate the unnecessary "do nothing" by negating the if, but I'm not sure what to do about the 's' part:

```
if((c != 30 && c != 3 && c != 4 && r != 'Y' && t != 'X') ...what goes here?...)
{
   function1();
}
```

I've tried both `&& (s >= 50000 || s <= 50999)` and `||(s < 50000 && s > 50999)` but those failed the test cases I ran.  When I tried `&&( s < 50000 || s > 50999))` all my test cases succeeded, but I know I can't test for everything and so I'm hoping someone with a stronger grasp of logical negation can tell me with certainty whether this is correct.

Comment: You could just `!` the whole expression.

Comment: @Dúthomhas no Karnaugh Maps, but [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: There's no benefit of adding an extra answer, as I wouldn't really be adding much, but I think it's worth noting here that this is a perfect example of where adding a unit test while working on legacy code is of great benefit. This is a perfect example as you can define exactly what it does now in the form of tests and then refractor safely. In fact, the tests act as documentation, in the form of examples, as to what the snippet does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work. However, it's a little redundant:

```
if((c != 30 && c != 3 && c != 4 && r != 'Y' && t != 'X') && (s < 50000 || s > 50999))
```

An easier way would be to just negate the entire statement:

```
if(!(c == 30 || c == 3 || c == 4 || r == 'Y' || t == 'X' ||( s>= 50000 && s <= 50999)))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a logical expression like

```
expr1 || expr2
```

then its negation

```
!( expr1 || expr2 )
```

is equivalent tp

```
!expr1 && !expr2
```

And vice versa if you have an expression like this

```
expr1 && expr2
```

then its negation

```
!( expr1 && expr2 )
```

is equivalent to

```
!expr1 || !expr2
```

So to negate this expression

```
c == 30 || c == 3 || c == 4 || r == 'Y' || t == 'X' ||( s>= 50000 && s <= 50999)
```

like

```
!( c == 30 || c == 3 || c == 4 || r == 'Y' || t == 'X' ||( s>= 50000 && s <= 50999))
```

we will get

```
!( c == 30 )&& !( c == 3 ) && !( c == 4 ) && !( r == 'Y' ) && !(t == 'X' ) && !( s>= 50000 && s <= 50999)
```

then

```
c != 30 && c != 3 && c != 4 && r != 'Y'&& t != 'X' && ( !( s>= 50000 ) || !( s <= 50999))
```

and at last

```
c != 30 && c != 3 && c != 4 && r != 'Y'&& t != 'X' && ( s < 50000 || s > 50999 )
```

Comment: Where do you get this stuff from? Do you just have a list of already pre-made answers?

Comment: Credits to [Augustus De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus_De_Morgan)...